# returning ArrayList gives error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, return, return-value

I am trying to return an ArrayList but at the very end i get error: cannot find symbol. I am adding to the list some Strings and Doubles and returning it to what called it.

error:

```
./Sample.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        return placeMatch;
               ^
  symbol:   variable placeMatch
  location: class Sample
1 error
```

taking into consideration what was mentioned about the try catch i moved my declaration statement to the top and i get:

./Sample.java:54: error: incompatible types
        return placeMatch;
               ^
  required: String
  found:    ArrayList

actual code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//...other imports

public class Sample
  extends UnicastRemoteObject
  implements SampleInterface {



    public Sample() throws RemoteException {

    }

    public String invert(String city, String state) throws RemoteException {
        try{


 ArrayList<Object> placeMatch = new ArrayList<Object>();
        // Read the existing address book.
        PlaceList place =
        PlaceList.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("places-proto.bin"));

        // Iterates though all people in the AddressBook and prints info about them.

        for (Place Placeplace: place.getPlaceList()) {
        //System.out.println("STATE: " + Placeplace.getState());
            if(Placeplace.getName().startsWith(city)){
                placeMatch.add(Placeplace.getName());
                placeMatch.add(Placeplace.getState());
                placeMatch.add(Placeplace.getLat());
                placeMatch.add(Placeplace.getLon());
                break;
            }


          }

        }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("opening .bin failed:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return placeMatch;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 8):

You need to declare:

```
ArrayList<Object> placeMatch = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

outside the try block.

Second question:

The method return type is `String`. You cannot return `ArrayList<Object>`.

The solution depends on what you need to do. You can change the return type:

```
public List<Object> invert(String city, String state) throws RemoteException {
```

Comment: fixed but i get incompatible types when returning now. Updated question.

Comment: If i do that then i get:
 error: cannot find symbol
    public List<Object> invert(String city, String state) throws RemoteException {
           ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class Sample

Comment: You need to include java.util.List or change it to ArrayList<Object>

Answer (score 1):

The parameter placeMatch is visible only in the try block. So if you want to initialize and declare this parameter in try block, you should return this parameter at the bottom of try block and in the catch block return null or something. BUT! If you could, declare this param outside try block, as a instance variable.

Comment: fixed but i get incompatible types when returning now. Updated question.

Comment: In the method declaration (invert) you promise your machine that you will return a String object but then you return an ArrayList of object from Object class. That's the reason why your VM is upset. Change return type in invert method decralation